# Cancel all NSTimers created in a loop from another method

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer

I'm creating a lot of timers from a loop in order to add cells to a TableView:

```
 for (NSInteger i = 0; i < media.products.count; i++) {
        NSDictionary *obj = [media.products objectAtIndex:i];
            NSInteger timeInterval = [[obj objectForKey:@"TIME"] integerValue];
            [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:timeInterval target:self selector:@selector(addNewProductToTableView:) userInfo:obj repeats:NO];
    }
```

I would like to cancel all of them when another controller is displayed, something like this in shouldSelectViewController or viewWillDisappear :

```
  NSLog(@"I've been called!");
// Doesn't seem to work :
  [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self]; 
  [NSTimer cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self]; 
// Clean the table
   self.dataSource = [NSMutableArray array];
   [self.tableView reloadData];
```

When the tableView is displayed again, a mix of the previous and current timers make cell display a mess.

Alternatively I wouldn't mind destroying the whole controller if it's simplier, but can't get it to work either.

```
self.view = nil; // ?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create `NSMutableArray *timers;` in interface of your viewcontroler
2. Initialize and allocate in viewDidload `timers = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];`
3. Change your loop code to

   `for (NSInteger i = 0; i < media.products.count; i++) {
           NSDictionary *obj = [media.products objectAtIndex:i];
           NSInteger timeInterval = [[obj objectForKey:@"TIME"] integerValue];
           NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:timeInterval target:self selector:@selector(addNewProductToTableView:) userInfo:obj repeats:NO];
           [timers addObject:timer];
       }`

And whereever you want to invalidate timer

```
for (NSTimer *timer in timers)
    [timer invalidate];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget` has nothing to do with `NSTimer`s. They cancel calls scheduled with [`performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:) (and its companion, `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:inModes:`). What you need to do is keep the timer you create around in a property and invalidate it when you need to cancel:

```
@protocol (nonatomic) NSTimer *timer;

...

self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:timeInterval target:self selector:@selector(addNewProductToTableView:) userInfo:obj repeats:NO];

...

[self.timer invalidate];
self.timer = nil;
```